# ElementTree XPath strange behaviour

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Hi
I'm using `ElementTree` (1.3) with Python 2.7 and enjoy XPath functionality,
however one of search results surprised me.

My XML example:

```
<OTF>
  <FECS state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
    <BackEndCompatibility major="2.2" state="disabled">
        <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0"/>
    </BackEndCompatibility>
  </FECS>
</OTF>
```

**Question 1:**
When I use `findall` to get first found element

```
version = "2.2.0.0"
found = list(txml.findall(".//BackEnd[@version='%s']" % version))
return found and found[0] or None
```

it finds nothing.

However when I change XML file, so that `BackEnd` element contains *subelements*,

```
        <BackEnd state="disabled" version="2.2.0.0">
           <any_dummy_element/> 
        </BackEnd>
```

then searched element is found properly.

Did you face such a behaviour?
Am I doing sth wrong or this is a bug in `ElementTree` implementation?

**Question 2:**
Another issue I have is `xmlns`.
Let's assume I change XML first line to contain `xmlns`:

```
<OTF xmlns="http://si-wiki/OTFCompatibility">
</OTF>
```

In such a case I have to change find string to:

```
".//{http://si-wiki/OTFCompatibility}BackEnd[@version='%s']"
```

Is there any way to tell ElementTree to ignore xmlns during parsing and treat all elements' names (including root) like they had no prefix?

Regards,
Zbigniew

Answer (score 1):

For question No1:
When I replaced lines

```
    found = list(txml.findall(".//BackEnd[@version='%s']" % version))
    return found and found[0] or None
```

with

```
    found = txml.findall(".//BackEnd[@version='%s']" % version)
    if found:
        return found[0]
    return None
```

then correct result is returned without dummy children hack.